# Saving multiple records on one create form dependign on associated items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Goal: To create multiple Orders based on how many of a certain associated records are present.

Here's the form: (not important but receiving errors

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |form| %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :cart_id, value: @cart.id %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :store_order_id, value: "1" %>
    <%= form.text_field :shipping_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :shipping_address1 %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil
>   or be empty):

Models:

ShopProduct

```
has_one :order
has_many :line_items
```

Order

```
belongs_to :product, optional: true
belongs_to :shop_product, optional: true
belongs_to :cart
```

LineItem

```
belongs_to :shop_product, optional: true
belongs_to :product, optional: true
belongs_to :cart
```

Cart

```
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
has_one :order
```

OrdersController:

```
  def create
    cart = Cart.find(params["order"]["cart_id"])
    line_items = LineItem.where(cart_id: cart)
    shop_product_line_items = line_items.where.not(shop_product: [nil, ""])
    product_line_items = line_items.where.not(product: [nil, ""])
    shop_products = ShopProduct.find(shop_product_line_items.each { |li| li.shop_product })
    products = Product.find(product_line_items.each { |li| li.product })

    if shop_products.present?
      shop_products.each { |sp|
      @order = Order.new
      @order.shop_product_id = sp.id
      @order.product_id = sp.product_id
      @order.cart_id = cart
      @order.save!
    }
    end

    if products.present?
      products.each { |p|
      @order = Order.new
      @order.product_id = p.id
      @order.cart_id = cart
      @order.save!
    }
    end

    @orders = Order.where(cart_id: cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @orders.count == line_items.count
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

How it works is there is a cart which then is attached to many `line_items` which can be `shop_product` or `product`.  I then want to save a separate order based on each `@cart.line_items`.

How can I create multiple Order's based on how many line_items are present in the cart?

Comment: Your specific error is likely caused by `@order` being nil. Not sure if this is the cause, but you should use `map` instead of `each` when building the lists of ids to pass to `find`. You should learn to use a debugger tool like byebug or pry and step through the code

Comment: Testing in console and found that `shop_product_line_items = line_items.where.not(shop_product_id: [nil, ""])` is coming up blank.  Is that how I should be finding out if the shop_product_id record is present?  Obviously not because it doesnt seem to be working but how else can i

Comment: Looks like using `.where(shop_product_id: present? )` works so far.. is that reliable? When i was doing this i read NOT to use something like that on SO --- not sure sure how good that information was

Comment: No, that is not proper syntax. You could use `where.not(shop_product_id: nil)` though

Comment: okay thanks.  going to re make this quesetion with updates

Comment: o welp nvm.  thanks for the hlp  --- using map and nil works and the orders are creating based on the amount of line items in the loop... appreciate it.  you help me a lot.  GOAT